# Robot Framework Match Regexp returns nothing

Tags: regex, testing, robotframework

The script is supposed to get the ip address from the websites given in a txt file. The script works as supposed to up until the Match Regexp part. The Regex itself works as intended when the same code is written in Python.

```
*** Variables ***
${ipregex}    (\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)

*** Test Cases ***
Ping Test
  ${filep}=  Get File   webpages.txt
  @{lines}=   Split To Lines  ${filep}
  FOR   ${line}   IN  @{lines}
    ${output}=  Run   ping ${line} -c 1
    ${result}=  Get Regexp Matches  ${output}  ${ipregex}  partial_match=true
    Log   ${result}
  END
```

I Appreciate any help!

[The empty return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtJML.jpg)

Comment: Literal dots  in the regex must be escaped, but that is not a problem here. What is in `${output}`? Are you sure this variable contains expected text?

Comment: Can you share the content of webpages.txt?

Comment: webpages.txt has three links
www.whitehouse.gov
www.iltalehti.fi
best.aliexpress.com

Comment: Example of output: ${output} = PING wh46.go-vip.net (192.0.66.168): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.0.66.168: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=26.800 ms
@WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Then try `\d+(?:\.\d+){3}`, without groupings.

Comment: Still nothing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash character with another backslash, see the [documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Regular%20expressions).
this example should produce the match you are looking for:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    String

***Variables***
${output}    PING wh46.go-vip.net (192.0.66.168): 56 data bytes 64 bytes from 192.0.66.168: icmp_seq=0 ttl=54 time=26.800 ms
${ipregex}    ((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\\d|[1-9]|)\\d)\\.?\\b){4}

*** Test Cases ***
test
    ${result}=    Get Regexp Matches    ${output}    ${ipregex}
    Log    ${result}
```